# React Native Push Notifications doesn't call onNotification method when app is closed

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I have used react-native-push-notification package. But onNotification callback method does not call when the app is closed but it works fine when the app is in the background or on foreground.

I have also changed `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />` but it did not work.

Here is AndroidMenifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.appname">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/logo" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:usesCleartextTraffic="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="appname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
    <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="true"/>
    <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@color/white"/>
    <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

    <!-- Notification icon -->
    <meta-data android:name = "com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <meta-data android:name = "com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: What is your targetSDKVersion ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to used firebase messaging

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
   console.log('Your message was handled in background');
});
```

for more information you need to prefer this link :- https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage